# Group images in media library

Tags: plugins, media-library

I'm looking for a method to group images in the media library.

I'm developing a photo portfolio site. I have uploaded all the images to the media library I need a way to group the images to make them more manageable.

At the moment I just have a long list of images.

Answer (score 2):

Attachments itself same as posts...
so you can think on giving tham meta_values or adding taxonomies to tham. as for me i always used first method... this is a simple example of how this functioonality works...

```
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "afields_to_edit",  10, 2);
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "afields_to_save",  10, 2);

   function afields_to_save($post, $attachment){
          $parentPost = get_post($post['post_parent']);       
          /*************************************************************
          // Roles
          *************************************************************/    

          if (isset($_POST['___attachments'][$post['ID']]['type']) 
              && trim($_POST['___attachments'][$post['ID']]['type']) != ""){

                 $type = $_POST['___attachments'][$post['ID']]['type'];
                 update_post_meta($post['ID'],  '_type',  $type);

           } else {

               delete_post_meta($post['ID'],  '_type');

           }
       return $post;
   }

   function afields_to_edit($form_fields, $post){

       $parentPost = get_post($post->post_parent);
      /***********************************************************************
       Roles
      ***********************************************************************/  
      $form_fields["roles"]["label"] = "File Role";
      $form_fields["roles"]["input"] = "html";

      $html .= "<select name='___attachments[".$post->ID."][type]' style='width:95%;'>";
      $html .= "<option value=''>Default Role</option>";

      $roles = apply_filters('roles_sidebar', array(), $post, $parentPost);


      if (is_array($roles) && count($roles) > 0){
          foreach($roles as $key=>$role){
              $html .= "<option value='".$key."' ".$role['select'].">".$role['name']."</option>";
          }
      }
      $html .= "</select>";


      $form_fields["roles"]["html"]  = $html;
      return $form_fields;
 }
```

I think you can continue work in this way...